# What is the most efficient implementation of for loop for ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I just recently finished an android project and I have done some extensive codes of ArrayList and doing looping stuffs on it. I have two sets example of loops here.

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> object = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

for(int c=0;c<object.size();c++){

}

for(SomeObject obj: object){

}
```

I think the second one is good if you don't need the incrementing value and I think far more readable and neat than the first. But what in the two loops is ideal or efficient to use in terms speed, performance and memory usage?

Comment: You're trying to out guess the JVM and that's nothing but a losing game. So don't do it. Please before you go further, read this article on [writing dumb code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Comment: Dalvik optimization may differ from other JVMs, so Android is valid

Comment: Opt for readable over questionable performance gains.  The JVM is smarter than you give it credit for :)

Comment: You should first profile it.

Comment: checkout http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops

Comment: @sandrstar: You should post that information as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggestions [from the Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops) the most efficient ways for making loop are:

```
public void one() {
    int sum = 0;
    Foo[] localArray = mArray;
    int len = localArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += localArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void two() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Foo a : mArray) {
        sum += a.mSplat;
    }
}
```

Please, note that these ways have same performance for devices with JIT. So, in cases then JIT is off (e.g. while debugging using Eclipse) You might observe different results (`two()` will be faster than `one()`)

**Update**
I've checked ArrayLists also by using the following code:

```
    final ArrayList<String> testArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        testArrayList.add(String.valueOf(i<<2));
    }

    final TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger("Loop", "ArrayLists");

    timings.addSplit("start");

    for (int loopCount = 0; loopCount < 1000; loopCount++) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < testArrayList.size(); i++) {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(testArrayList.get(i));
        }
    }

    timings.addSplit("zero()");

    for (int loopCount = 0; loopCount < 1000; loopCount++) {
        int sum = 0;
        final int len = testArrayList.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(testArrayList.get(i));
        }
    }

    timings.addSplit("one()");

    for (int loopCount = 0; loopCount < 1000; loopCount++) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (String item : testArrayList) {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(item);
        }
    }

    timings.addSplit("two()");
    timings.dumpToLog();
```

And obtained the following output (with JIT):

```
ArrayLists: begin
ArrayLists:      0 ms, start
ArrayLists:      2713 ms, zero()
ArrayLists:      1753 ms, one()
ArrayLists:      1922 ms, two()
ArrayLists: end, 6388 ms
```

So, we able to see, that variants `one()` and `two()` provides similar results, and these results are faster than `zero()` (so, results look similar to ones described in the documentation for arrays).

Comment: The question isn't about arrays, it is about ArrayList. Not relevant.

Comment: Do you think Arrays are not relevant to ArrayList or has significant performance diffences then using in loops?

Comment: Updated the answer with my measurements on ArrayLists.

Comment: Thank you for this @sandrstar. Did you do this in eclipse? is JIT a plugin in eclipse?

Comment: I've created project in eclipse to profile. JIT is not part of eclipse, checkout http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2010/05/dalvik-jit.html here for some brief description of it.